# Filter rows by matching comma separated list against comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-like

I have the below table

```
Col1       Col2
1          ACA,ABS,PHR
2          PHR
3          MCM
4          ABC
```

Now I want to filter the data from this so if I have a filter parameter as say `'ABS,MCM'` I want to get only the rows which have at least one matching code. So in this case I should get the filtered result as

```
Col1       Col2
1          ACA,ABS,PHR
2          MCM
```

Now I can use the query `Select * from myTable where Col2 in ('ABS','MCM')` but then it won't retrieve the first row `ACA,ABS,PHR`. Can some one please tell me how I can do a text search for codes so as long as one code matches in Col2 I get the row so I can pass in directly the , delimited list and as long as it finds a single match the row is retrieved.

Thanks

Comment: Another great example illustrating why data should be kept in a third order form. Each column in table 1 should have one value.

Comment: If you can't fix your table, what about accepting a user defined table as a parameter? You could then join the UDT to the table on Col2 like UDT.col + '%'. Last route would be split the string into a table and then do the join.

Comment: That is not a bad idea..I could do that.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the LIKE operator, as follows :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE Col2 LIKE '%ABS%' OR Col2 LIKE '%MCM%'
```

---

If you are looking to accept a comma separated value as input for the search, then you may use STRING_SPLIT() (available since SQL Server 2016) :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (SELECT val FROM STRING_SPLIT('ABS, MCM', ',')) x
    WHERE CONCAT(',', t.Col1, ',')
        LIKE CONCAT('%,', x.val, ',%')
)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have had mentioned in my question..Like I know would work but I was curious how I can just use the ,separated parameter directly

Comment: @user1221989 : ok, let me refine my answer then

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` was added in sql server 2016

Comment: @forpas : right... I did not pay attention to the sqlserver-2012 tag. I just updated my answer to mention 2016.

Comment: This will still give results which are supersets of 'ABS' or 'MCM'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `like` operator for `concat(',', col2, ',')`:

```
select * from tablename
where 
  concat(',', col2, ',') like '%,ABS,%'
  or
  concat(',', col2, ',') like '%,MCM,%'
```

So `',ACA,ABS,PHR,' like '%,ABS,%'` returns `true`

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE Col2 LIKE '%ABS%'
OR Col2 LIKE '%MCM%'
```

Comment: Why didn't you do this using a procedure which takes comma delimited string and matches each string and return all the matched results, using a loop and/or union.